# Force escape/close program/session in CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I wanted to see description of `sort`command but as always forgot to type most important thing - `/?` in this case. Now I'm stuck in entering lines inside this program and I have no idea how to end it or if I even can. And this happens not the first time and not with only `sort`

Is there any way I can stop such program and return to `cmd` context?

I know I can just simply close the window and open another one but say I'm in some crazy directory and have many crazy long commands in history, and stored some crazy important variables and I would like to keep all of this craziness. I hope it must be something for such issue right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break out of any program in cmd by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

The display will say ^C and you will then get your prompt back.

Also, remember, you can pipe any command to the `more` command so it automatically stops once the screen is full, so you can carefully read without the need to use the scrollbar.

So in your example, that would be `sort /? |more`

Comment: it's says that I've asked question 7min ago, but When I try to click the bird it's gives error "You can accept answer in 6min"?

Comment: unless it is relative to your response...

Comment: Yeah, has something to do with how much reputation you have, so you can't accept answers very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Some programs not responding to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> might do with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> and if you have really fast fingers you can halt output temporarily with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>and continue with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> (in most cases any key will continue).

Comment: Now I feel like total noob. What is Break key? :)

Comment: Never mind, It's labeled only `Pause` on my keyboard... :)